# Difference between 間【あいだ】 and 間【ま】

Tags: words, readings

What is the difference between the words 間【あいだ】 and 間【ま】 ? Both seem to have the basic meaning *space or time interval*.

Comment: as an "independent word", あいだ.

Comment: @virmaior By "independent word" I meant "not in a compound". (In a compound it is of course pronounced　かん or けん.) I have rephrased the question to make it clearer.

Comment: No, the rules aren't that clear.  間{かん} is a word, and 間{ま} appears in compounds such as 間近・隙間・間違い・間際・居間・手間・間口・谷間・マヌケ and in the lexicalized adverbs 間もなく and いつの間に.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both readings can mean "between" (see meanings 1, 2, 4, and 5 of [*aida*](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/949/m0u/) and first meaning of the noun [*ma*](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/206542/m0u/%E3%81%BE/)). But *aida* seems to be more common to express a space between two (or more) things, while *ma* expresses a space as such, or the type of partition of a space (see the second and third meaning of the noun *ma*), such as a floor plan.

*aida* can carry the temporal meaning "during, while" (meaning 3 of *aida*), and following a nominal marked with *-no* it can mean "among" (meaning 6 of *aida*).

*ma* can also express a period of time, as in the above-mentioned 間もなく 'ma-mo na-ku', or 間に合う 'ma-ni a-u'. It can, more specifically, express the moments during a conversation when nothing is said (meaning 6 of the noun *ma*).
There are further, specialized meaning of both words, and there are, of course, also some instances of grammaticalized use (the temporal meaning 'during, while' of *aida* would fall in this class, imo).

To summarize, *aida* means mostly "between", while *ma* means "space", its way of partitioning, and "period of time".

Answer (score 9):

As a part of a sino-japanese word you get カン・ケン readings as you suggest.

My sense is that if you just see the character lying about somewhere, the reading is あいだ.

The [Japanese wiktionary](http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%96%93) has some helpful ideas in its list of meanings for the character in Japanese, namely 4, 6, and 7 where they think it only works for ま

> 6.部屋。

when it means a room, it is always ま

> 1. めぐりあわせ、運、タイミング。

When it refers to timing it is always ま

As a parenthetical, it can also be pronounced ま in a "compound": [合間]{あいま}. Cf. all of the room words ([居間]{いま}). And even あいだ in [間柄]{あいだがら}

There's also a set list of phrases where ま seems to be used:

```
間に合う
いつの間
束の間
```

But at least I would say the character used for native Japanese words is あいだ unless otherwise known to be ま.

Comment: There is also 間に合う (まにあう), to be in time; and 間もなく (まもなく), soon, in a short time.

Comment: But I agree with your answer; あいだ seems to be the default, while ま is used in certain special cases.

Comment: also いつの間にか, which also uses ma