# How do I read 間 in 食べている間に読みます?

Tags: words, kanji, readings

> 私は食べている**間**に読みます。

How do I read it?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%96%93

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between 間【あいだ】 and 間【ま】](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16107/difference-between-%e9%96%93-%e3%81%82%e3%81%84%e3%81%a0-and-%e9%96%93-%e3%81%be). Especially the highest-voted, but not-accepted answer applies here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read it as あいだ in this case.

Comment: Another example: あなたはどのくらいの間、神戸に住んでいますか。